# Custom hotkey works unstable

Tags: keyboard, finder, finder-tag

I've set up a hotkey "control + T" to quickly add tags to files in Finder. To do this, I went to system preferences > keyboard > Shortcuts > App shortcuts > and added a shortcut for the "Tags..." command in Finder. It works just fine until something happens and this hotkey would put focus onto folder which name starts with T. My best guess is that there may be another app that uses the same hotkey, but I didn't manage to figure out what app could cause this. Rebooting my mac fixes this issue but then it happens again. I have a Macbook Pro 14" 2021 with macOS Monterey 12.0.1 installed.

How do I get rid of such Finder behavior?

Comment: RE: "My best guess is that there may be another app that uses the same hotkey, but I didn't manage to figure out what app could cause this." --  If you are pressing **⌃T** when **Finder** has focus then no other _application_ should be usurping the _keyboard shortcut_unless you have also assigned that _keyboard shortcut_ to an _application_ that can create _global keyboard shortcuts_, e.g **Karabiner-Elements** or similar.  Try using **⌃⌥⌘T** instead.

Comment: @user3439894 I don't use any apps that can set global shortcuts. Or there might be any but I'm not aware of such functionality in them. I'll try using ⌃⌥⌘T but this one seems like a huge setback in accessibility. Would it be a problem if I'd use both shortcuts for the same target function?

Comment: I tried to add two shortcuts for the same function at once and found out that it's not possible. I changed the "Tags..." shortcut from ⌃T to ⌃⌥⌘T and it didn't work right away. It only worked after I rebooted a mac.